# Battery drains suddenly from 18% to 5% , laptop hibernates

Tags: laptop, battery

I bought a new Aspire E5-572G-525V laptop and using windows 8.1, but I am facing a battery issue.

Up to 20% the battery works fine and giving good backup, but I have noticed that whenever the battery level reaches below 20% (around 18%), the battery suddenly drops to 5%-critical level without giving a low battery indication and the laptop gets hibernate.

I have tried all the possible ways like to set the low level battery level indication in advanced battery options, re-installing the Microsoft battery driver etc. but nothing has worked.

Is the battery is defected or is it any hardware or software issue?

Comment: Have you profiled the battery? This isn't normally available under power options, but there is usually an OEM application to do it.

Comment: Try to manually calibrate the battery by fully charging to 100%  then let it cool for an hour or so and then a full discharge till Windows  hibernates.

Comment: If this is a new laptop, it is under warranty. Call support. If there is a problem, they will be able to warranty replace it. That being said, I would check for a BIOS update before I did anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, this is caused by an aging battery. Your claim that the laptop is new is questionable because the system has an older (*Haswell*) processor and is running Windows 8.1 rather than Windows 10. (Perhaps it was [new old stock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_old_stock)?)

An older battery tends to have high **[internal resistance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_resistance)**. This means that the battery's voltage will drop more under load than if it's new, and therefore the battery's fuel gauge may be out of sync with the actual **[state-of-charge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_of_charge)** curve (e.g. a battery at 11.1V may have about 40% charge when new but the same voltage may indicate a less than 10% SoC on an old battery).

The first thing to try is to calibrate the battery. Fully charge the battery, then fully discharge it. This will typically reset the battery's fuel gauge to its proper levels. Otherwise, the battery is faulty and you will probably need to replace it.

---

For what it's worth, while lithium-ion batteries do degrade with non-use, when stored correctly, this degradation can be reduced to a minimum. A battery that is stored at a 30-50% state of charge and at a low (but not freezing) temperature will retain nearly all of its capacity even after several years. However, if the battery is fully charged or completely discharged and/or is stored in very high temperatures, it can lose much of its capacity in a years' time.

I suspect your laptop was stored in a totally discharged state for an extended period of time before it was sold to you, which may have led to the situation you're encountering. Perhaps the best way to monitor your battery's status and condition is to use NirSoft's free [BatteryInfoView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/battery_information_view.html) utility. I always have it running on my laptop and it proved very handy in diagnosing battery issues.